# Differentiate between Present Simple vs Present Progressive (Continuous)

Tags: present-tense, continuous-aspect, present-progressive

Is the following sentence in present simple or continuous tense?

> **I am in class.**

How do you change it to the other tense?

Comment: Please give an example of what you think the present simple and present continuous are, and clarify why you're having a problem with the particular sentence in the question.

Comment: Perhaps you need to review what those tenses mean before asking how to change something that is not relevant. Also, this question belongs on ELL, and not here.

Answer (score 1):

**I am in class** - is a declarative clause in the Present Simple.

Subject= **I**

verb= **am** acts here as a linking verb or copula, and thus the clause's verb

your complement - **in class**(might be an adjunct, not too sure) doesn't allow for the sentence to be said in Present Progressive.

**I am being in class** does not work because you need a "dynamic adjective" as a complement for it to work.

as in:

*I am being nice*, *or I am being funny*.

Nice and funny are adjectives that can complement **be** in Present Progressive ( there aren't too many of those).